# Pandas: handle missing column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using the following code to read a CSV file in chunks using pandas `read_csv`

```
headers = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
fields = ["1", "5"]

for chunk in pandas.read_csv(fileName, names=headers, header=0, usecols=fields, chunksize=chunkSize):
```

Sometimes my CSV won't have column "5" and I want to be able to handle this case and specify some default values. Is there a way to read just the headers of my CSV file without reading the whole file so I can handle this manually? Or may be any other clever way to default the value for the missing column?

Comment: Possibly set `error_bad_lines=False`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the thing is I need the value for column "5" for each row, however sometimes the whole column "5" will be missing so I have to fallback to default values. error_bad_lines=False will just ignore the row, no?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Not sure about this one. I always believed pandas would fill NaNs by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `nrows=0` this reads just the column row, you can then call `intersection` to find the common column values and avoid any errors:

```
In[14]:
t="""1,2,3,5,6
0,1,2,3,4"""
headers = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
fields = ["1", "5"]
cols = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), nrows=0).columns
cols

Out[14]: Index(['1', '2', '3', '5', '6'], dtype='object')
```

So now we have column names we can call `intersection` to find the valid columns against your expected and actual columns:

```
In[15]:
valid_cols = cols.intersection(headers)
valid_cols

Out[15]: Index(['1', '2', '3', '5'], dtype='object')
```

You can do the same with `fields` and then you can pass these to your current code to avoid any exceptions

Just to demonstrate that passing `nrows=0` just reads the header row:

```
In[16]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), nrows=0)

Out[16]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
Index: []
```

Comment: yeah I just found about nrows but I was about to test it with nrows=1, didn't know the count starts from 0 (should've guessed) I will give it a try thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's not obvious that you can do this, will update to prove this